# Integrating a rational function with square roots

Tags: integration

Solve :$$\int _ 0 ^ {\infty}{x^2\over (2+x^2)^{3/2}}dx  = \int _ 0 ^ {\pi/2} \tan^2 {\theta} \cos {\theta} \,d{\theta}=[\sec{\theta}+\cos {\theta}]_0 ^{\pi/2}$$

I've tried to do it and got the answer as upper limit is becoming divergent, then what to do? Please help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think the integral is not divergent? The left-hand integrand behaves like $1/x$ as $x\to\infty$, which does diverge.

Comment: @ Chris:  The  UL is indeed divergent, they are tan and sec functions ... its ok.

Comment: @Chris This is a gentle reminder to consider accepting an answer if your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let's try integration by parts

$$\int x\cdot\dfrac x{(2+x^2)^{3/2}}\ dx=x\int\dfrac x{(2+x^2)^{3/2}}\ dx-\int\left(\dfrac{dx}{dx}\cdot\int\dfrac x{(2+x^2)^{3/2}}\ dx\right)dx$$

Set $\sqrt{2+x^2}=y\implies2+x^2=y^2,x\ dx=y\ dy$

$$\int\dfrac x{(2+x^2)^{3/2}}\ dx=\int\dfrac{y\ dy}{y^3}=-\dfrac1y=?$$

Use [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html) for $$\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}=\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+2}|+K$$

The definite integral $[0,\infty]$ is divergent as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+2}|=?$$

Comment: This works, but a simpler method is to bound the integral below by $\int_{100}^\infty 1/(2x)\,dx$. I just wanted to give an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

For large $x$, the integrand behaves as $1/x$ and thus your integral to infinity diverges logarithmically. The indefinite integral is

$$
I(x)=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}} + \sinh^{-1}(x/\sqrt{2})
$$

By trig substitution. $I(0)=0$. For large $x$, the first term on the right is finite (and equal to $-1$), but the second term is singular. Using the [series for large argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Series_expansions)

$$
\sinh^{-1}(z)=\ln(2z) + \mathcal{O}(1/z^2) \ \ , \ z \to \infty
$$

So we have for the principle part of your integral

$$
\int\limits_0^a dx \frac{x^2}{(2+x^2)^{3/2}} = \ln(a\sqrt{2}) -1 +\mathcal{O}(1/a^2) \ \ , \ \ a \to \infty
$$

Here is a plot:[image]